# antt is not compatible with fontspec

Tags: fontspec

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{anttor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123$0123$
\end{document}
```

run well when I compiled with pdflatex; while

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{anttor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
0123$0123$
\end{document}
```

not so well with xelatex. The numbers in math mode is typesetting in CM fonts.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried passing the option `no-math` to `fontspec`?

Comment: I've deleted my answer since @egreg's answer (which expands on Mico's comment) is a better one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the math fonts coming with Antykwa Torunska also with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{anttor}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Antykwa Torunska Condensed}

\begin{document}
0123$0123\sum_{i=1}^n \sin n\phi$
\end{document}
```

The important thing is to load `anttor` before `fontspec`, to which the `no-math` option should be given.

[image]